# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Spring cyclic dependency - constructor Autowiring

Tags: java, spring

Old code:

```
@Component("someFactory")
public class SomeFactoryImpl implements SomeFactory{

    @Autowired
    private List<SomeTransformer<?, ?>> someTransformers;
```

New code:

```
@Component("someFactory")
public class SomeFactoryImpl implements SomeFactory {

    private List<SomeTransformer<?, ?>> someTransformers;

    @Autowired
    public SomeFactoryImpl(List<SomeTransformer<?, ?>> someTransformers) {
        this.someTransformers = someTransformers;
     }
```

Here I got:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'someFactory': Requested bean is
>   currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

Does Spring have some problems when autowiring through constructor?

Comment: I suppose you have multiple beans defined of type SomeTransformer you wish to inject? Can you post the code of these beans? What type of configuration do you use? XML? Annotated?

Comment: Yeas, I propably have some circular dependency but my question is why it works on old code ? How spring works here? I don't want fix the circularity but know what is the difference in resolving beans in both codes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) (Look for 'Circular dependencies').

> Unlike the typical case (with no circular dependencies), a circular
>   dependency between bean A and bean B forces one of the beans to be
>   injected into the other prior to being fully initialized itself (a
>   classic chicken/egg scenario).

The difference lies in the following;

In **Setter injection**, the bean references will only be constructed once they are required. You can probably recreate the same problem with setter injection when annotating the setter with @Required as this will cause the bean to be created immediately.

In **Constructor injection**, Spring cannot decide which of the beans should be created first because they depend on one another. The problem is exposed immediately. A possible workaround is using constructor injection annotated with @Lazy;

```
@Component
public class CircularClassA {

    private CircularClassB classB;

    @Autowired
    public CircularDependencyB(@Lazy CircularClassB classB) {
        this.classB = classB;
    }
}
```

This will create only a proxy of classB instead of fully initializing it. It gets fully initialized when needed, just as with setter injection.